# How can I include an underline in a ConTeXt \setuphead

Tags: context, underline

I am currently using:

```
\setuphead[section]      [style=\tfb\bf, color=titlegrey, align=right]
```

How can this be modified to include an underline (or underbar)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\setuphead
  [section]
  [style=\tfb\bf,
   deeptextcommand=\underbar,
   color=titlegrey,
   align=right]

\definehead
  [mysection]
  [section]
  [deeptextcommand=\underbars]


\starttext
\section[title={This is supposed to be underlined, and it is. Or is it?}]

\samplefile{ward}

\mysection[title={This is supposed to be underlined, and it is. Or is it?}]

\samplefile{ward}

\stoptext
```

[image: En underbar figur]

Comment: This is almost working for me.  Is there a way to also have the spaces in between words underlined? Thank you!

Comment: As in the first section?

Comment: I have it working now. I just used your `\setuphead[section]` without needing to use `\definehead`

Comment: @mickep just highlighted the difference between `\underbar` and `\underbars`